# Reference request for a class of abstract optimization problems over function spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, optimization, reference-request, unbounded-operators

Let $A : \mathcal{D}(X) \subseteq X \to X$ be an unbounded linear operator on some Banach space $X$ of real-valued functions. I am looking for a reference on solutions to optimization problems of the following form:

$$
  \mathrm{min}_{f \in \mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{D}(A)} (Af)(0),
$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is some convex subset of $\mathcal{D}(A)$.

**Example problem:** Take $X = L_{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$, $Af = \mathrm{div}f = \partial_{x_1}f + \partial_{x_2}f$, $\mathcal{D}(A) = C^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is some abstract convex subset of $C^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$.

Comment: This is too vague because too general. There will be methods but they will be adapted to the specific type of problems at hand. However, I suspect that in many cases you can just adapt some ideas of the calculus of variations or use ideas from optimization by vector space methods (see the book by Luenberger of the same name).